# Change title when drilldown in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm looking for a way to show a info text in Highcharts when using drilldowns. I want a text that tells my visitors that another chart has been showed up. A title for example:
"New chart - more about Animals"

http://jsfiddle.net/6zYmJ/

Do you have any ideas how to do that?

```
$(function () {    

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals2',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals2'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits2',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits2'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars2',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars2'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        },{
            id: 'animals2',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits2',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars2',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
})
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For example using `drilldown` and `drillup` events ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown)), a couple of variables and `Chart.setTitle` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle)). Like this:

```
var defaultTitle = "Basic drilldown";
var drilldownTitle = "More about ";

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            drilldown: function(e) {
                chart.setTitle({ text: drilldownTitle + e.point.name });
            },
            drillup: function(e) {
                chart.setTitle({ text: defaultTitle });
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: defaultTitle
    },
    // ... more options
});
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/fzt149d7/).

Comment: Thank you - it worked! Do you know if it's also possible to get the value of the series name, in this case "Things"? I tried with e.series.name, but it didn't work.

Comment: I am doing a 3 layer drill down, when I drill UP from the third to second layer, is it possible to assign the name of the second series?

Comment: @Hanoncs I believe `chart.setTitle({text: e.seriesOptions.name});` should do the trick.

Comment: in the event handlers `this` refers to the chart object. So you can call `this.setTitle(...)`.